# Zend_Db_Select not found

Tags: magento-1.9, php, zend-framework

Magento site is not loading. It's error log is showing PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Zend_Db_Select' not found in select.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error says, your Magento  instance does not have one of it's library file `Zend_Db_Select` which you can usually found at `lib/Zend/Db/Select.php`. So put that file in that particular location will resolve this issue. You can find **[Zend_Db_Select](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/lib/Zend/Db/Select.php)** class here.

If the error continues to give the same "MISSING" error with other library files after you have placed this file, then it gives a clear hint that your Magento instance is some how messed up. You need to find the missing library files and then need to replace it in your instance.